# How to bind different links to different text tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have application which scrapes some info from web and then prints the results on GUI as text. Some part of that text is link and i want to bind text to link that user could able to go to the correct link. (every text goes to different page when clicked) but the biggest issue is, that my program scans the web and if it finds the correct info it prints on GUI (tkinter) and because of that i can`t figure out the solution cause otherwise i will write manually functions to bind text to link.

So my question is How can i bind text to different links if my program prints new text after some time?

There is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.Scrol = Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.Text = Text(self.master, height=50, width=500)

        self.Scrol.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.Text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.Scrol.config(command=self.Text.yview)
        self.Text.config(yscrollcommand=self.Scrol.set)

        self.Text.tag_configure('red', foreground='red')
        self.Text.tag_configure('blue', foreground='blue')


        line1 = "This is line 1 with link: "
        myLink1 = "My_link1"
        line2 = "This is line 2 with link: link: "
        myLink2 = "My_link2"

        self.Text.insert(END, line1 + " ", "red")
        self.Text.insert(END, myLink1 + "\n", "blue")

        self.Text.insert(END, line2 + " ", "red")
        self.Text.insert(END, myLink2 + "\n", "blue")

        self.master.after(1000, self.more_text)


    def more_text(self):

        line3 = "This is line n with link: "
        my_link3 = "My_link3"
        self.Text.insert(END, line3 + " ", "red")
        self.Text.insert(END, my_link3 + "\n", "blue")

        self.Text.bind('<Button-1>', self.showLink)

        self.master.after(2000, self.more_text)

    def showLink(self, event):
        webbrowser.open('google.com')



top = Tk()
top.geometry('1000x1000')
app = Window(top)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand. _"How can i bind text to different links if my program prints new text after some time?"_ Is your program _not_ doing that already?

Comment: At the moment every text is binded to the same page: google.com i want to bind every text to different pages

Comment: Of your predetermined choosing?

Comment: Yes, Every text piece: "My_link3" is my link name.

Comment: _"At the moment every text is binded to the same page"_ is _incorrect_. Your _entire_ `Text` widget keeps getting bound to the same function that goes to `'google.com'` when user clicks anywhere in the `Text` widget. What you should instead use is [`tag_bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.tag_bind-method). Also see [Tkinter Text Widget Hyperlink Manager](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm).

Comment: Thanks Nae. I found a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couples of days i came up with solution to my problem:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.Scrol = Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.Text = Text(self.master, height=50, width=500)

        self.Scrol.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.Text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.Scrol.config(command=self.Text.yview)
        self.Text.config(yscrollcommand=self.Scrol.set)

        self.Text.tag_configure('red', foreground='red')
        self.Text.tag_configure('blue', foreground='blue')
        self.Text.tag_configure('hlink', foreground='blue', underline=1)


        line1 = "This is line 1 with link: "
        myLink1 = "My_link1"
        line2 = "This is line 2 with link: link: "
        myLink2 = "My_link2"

        self.Text.insert(END, line1 + " ", "red")
        self.Text.insert(END, myLink1 + "\n", "blue")

        self.Text.insert(END, line2 + " ", "red")
        self.Text.insert(END, myLink2 + "\n", "blue")


        self.master.after(1000, self.more_text)


    def more_text(self):
        line3 = "This is line n with link: "
        my_link3 = "My_link3"
        self.Text.insert(END, line3 + " ", "red")
        self.Text.insert(END, my_link3 + "\n", "hlink")

        self.Text.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.openHLink)

        self.master.after(2000, self.more_text)

    def openHLink(self, event):
        start, end = self.Text.tag_prevrange("hlink",
        self.Text.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y)))
        webbrowser.open(self.Text.get(start, end))

top = Tk()
top.geometry('1000x1000')
app = Window(top)

top.mainloop()
```

Now every time new My_link3 link appears on the screen a user can click on it and web browser will open it. As i mention in my question earlier i wanted to go to my_link3 which was different every time and this answer solved my problem. Hope it will help someone..

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer!